# how can I use the image in a link with more tags in Yii2 Framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

hi to all i want to ask that how to use the image in a link with more tags in Yii2 Framework, I am doing like this, it showing the image and echoing the speaker name but I want to create the click event.

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <img class="speakerimg" 
        src="<?= Yii::getAlias('../adminpanel/web').$speaker->image_path; ?>">
    <span style="margin: 0 0 0 20px;">
        <?= $speaker->speaker_name;?>
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: You need image as anchor?

Answer (score 1):

Please do it as

```
 use yii\helpers\Url;

 $themeUrl = $this->theme->baseUrl;

 $logoimg = Html::img($themeUrl.'/img/ats/logo2.png', ['alt'=>'Image']);

 echo Html::a($logoimg.$speaker->speaker_name,Url::to(['site/index'])); ?>
```

Please paste it in the loop in which you will show images with text.

Answer (score 0):

**i solved it something like this**

```html
<?php
foreach ($speakers as $speaker):?>
<?php $imageUrl = Yii::getAlias('../adminpanel/web').$speaker->image_path; ?>

<div class="list-group">
  <?php $speakerimg=Html::img($imageUrl, 
  ['alt'=>'Image', 'class'=>'speakerimg']); ?>

  <?php 
    echo Html::a(
    $speakerimg.'<span style="margin: 0 0 0 20px;">'.
    $speaker->speaker_name.'</span>'.
    '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right 
    fa-2x pull-right" 
    aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top:33px";></i>',
    Url::to(['site/speakerdtl',
    'speaker_id'=>$speaker->id]), 
    ['class'=>'list-group-item']

  ); 
?>

</div>

<?php endforeach ?>
```